# Button will not go on the same line as list-item text

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styles

I have a unordered list with list items. Each list item has a button. The button does not seem to be able to go on the same line as the li-text -- this seems to be due to the li element having a default display of list-item. The problem with changing this display in the CSS is that if I change the display of list-item to be inline, the whole list messes up its formatting and the li::marker seems to disappear.

Does anyone know how to circumvent li-text to let a button sit next to it?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's the problem?

```html
<ul>
<li>some item <button>press</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is correct. 
I've also seen/used the following where you dress a anchor tag as a pseudo-button.
<ul>
<li>some item <a href="#" class="button">press</a></li>
</ul>